If I take a photo of a building from public street, can i use it in a post or book without permission?
Lets say i take a photo of a building or another structure from a public location, do I need permission from the building's owner or architect to use that photo in a book? This is to explain a certain subject in the book. Let's say the facade. I take photo of a building with a beautiful or interesting facade and show it as an example and say a thing or two below it. Again this is the outline / general view of the structure, as it is visible from public street.

Wikipedia: Freedom of panorama. It's complicated.

Where? The regulations on freedom of panorama differ greatly between countries.

I wonder if Google Street View, which photographs every street of every country it can access, seeks permission from every property owner and designer. What is does try to do, is to blur faces, vehicle IDs, house numbers etc. i.e. data pertaining to individuals.

@PMF. USA as you understood
